# Updating record on form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a form that is bound to a query (just a select from a table).

There is a blank date field on the form, and when the user enters a date and clicks the 'Save' button, I am running this VBA:

```
If IsDate(Me.PaidDate) = True Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "BeneEmployeePaidUnitsUpdateQry"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Else
    Me.Dirty = False
    ' Omitted code
End If

Me.Refresh
Me.Requery
```

The query I am running simply sets a field in another table to a value, but only if the date field in the table the user is updating (the date field on the form) is not null.

Now, a problem with continuous forms seems to be that if the user merely enters the date and clicks the 'Save' button without doing any other actions, the date is not immediately saved into the table and the query doesn't work because the date field is still null when it's getting hit.

I tried to cut a corner by using `acCmdSaveRecord` but that doesn't seem to be working for this scenario.

Note: Each record on the continuous form has its' own `Save` button.

Why do I need to run `acCmdSaveRecord` on the `AfterUpdate` event for that field? Is that my only option? Do continuous forms only perform updates to bound fields after that record has lost focus?

Comment: Is there just one save button or does each form have its own?

Comment: @rontornambe each record/row has its' own save button. This is actually mandatory for the functionality. Sorry I didn't specify.

Comment: What does the select statement look like? Is the primary key included?

Comment: @rontornambe I am wondering/thinking/agreeing that the missing PK in the sql statement was indeed the issue. I even read documentation about that like 3 weeks ago. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @rontornambe If you wanna throw that in an answer, I'll upvote & accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior can sometimes be attributed to when the primary key is not included in the query. In order for the correct record to be updated, a primary (or unique) key is required.